# OpenTelemetry Serverless Example not working

Tags: aws-lambda, open-telemetry

I'm trying to follow the serverless example here: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/serverless/

I setup this example exactly as described, including NODE_OPTIONS but when I run my lambda, I get "Metrics may not be exported for the lambda function because we are not force flushing before callback" and lots of "Instrumentation suppressed, returning Noop span".
As outlined by the error, no traces show up in my collector.

I am trying to avoid a lambda layer at the moment if possible